# indefinite call to "set function()" in JavaScript ES6 class

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, callstack

I am running this simple class in JavaScript but in console it give me a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error. and help?!?

```
class Person {

        constructor(name, age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        get name() {
            return String(this.name);
        }
        get age() {
            return String(this.age);
        }

        set name(name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        set age(age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
}

let p1 = new Person('Ehsan', 23);
```

this is a screen shot of the console

[image: here is the screen shot of console] }

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: My mistake, its because of setter because you are setting the same prop in setter and calling it over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to indicate that the `age` property should not be directly used, you should use a different property name than the name used by setters and getters. If the property that the setter / getter sets or gets is the same name as the setter or getter, it'll just keep calling itself, resulting in your error.

A common convention is to put an underscore before the property:

```js
class Person {

  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  get name() {
    return String(this._name);
  }
  get age() {
    return String(this._age);
  }

  set name(name) {
    this._name = name;
  }

  set age(age) {
    this._age = age;
  }
}

let p1 = new Person('Ehsan', 23);
console.log(p1.age);
p1.age = 32;
console.log(p1.age);
```

But the property is still viewable by consumers via `p1._age` - if you wanted to prevent that, you can make it more private with a closure and `WeakMap`:

```js
const Person = (() => {
  const privateVals = new WeakMap();
  return class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
      const privateObj = {};
      privateObj.name = name;
      privateObj.age = age;
      privateVals.set(this, privateObj);
    }

    get name() {
      return String(privateVals.get(this).name);
    }
    get age() {
      return String(privateVals.get(this).age);
    }

    set name(name) {
      privateVals.get(this).name = name;
    }

    set age(age) {
      privateVals.get(this).age = age;
    }
  }
})();

let p1 = new Person('Ehsan', 23);
console.log(p1.age);
p1.age = 32;
console.log(p1.age);
```

Comment: why is this happening
I am just passively creating a setter function

Comment: The setter is called `name` or `age`, and inside `name` or `age`, you're also calling `name` or `age`. A function which always calls itself before returning will result in the stack overflow that you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a getter / setter pair and a field with the same name. `this.name =` inside the setter will itself call the setter. If you really need a getter / setter, use another field, e.g. `this._name =` ... But to be honest: Don't use a getter / setter here. If you do `person.name = 15` you should rather fix that than trying to do that with getters / setters.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just have to rename your class variables in your constructor and then you should be good to go?

```
class Person {

  constructor(name, age) {
    this._name = name;
    this._age = age;
  }

  get name() {
    return String(this._name);
  }
  get age() {
    return String(this._age);
  }

  set name(name) {
    this._name = name;
  }

  set age(age) {
    this._age = age;
  }
}
```